# Getting a table column data as array with POST request in CakePHP

Tags: php, cakephp, cakephp-3.0, cakephp-4.x

I have a form that has a table inside it and that table has a quantity column, I want to get the quantity of all products and put them in a quantity array in the controller, is there a way I can do that? For now, it doesn't work when I click Update Cart button. Here is my current code:

> index page

```
<section class="section service border-top">
    <div>
    <?= $this->Form->create(null) ?>
    <fieldset>

        <?php if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && !empty($_SESSION['cart'])){?>
        <table id="cart-table" class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
            <tr>
                <th><?= 'Products' ?></th>
                <th><?= 'Price'?></th>
                <th><?= 'Quantity'?></th>
                <th><?= 'Sub Total'?></th>
            </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
            <?php foreach ($cart_items as $cart_item): ?>
                <tr>
                    <td><?= $cart_item->name;?></td>
                    <td><span id="price"><?= "$ AU".$cart_item->price;?></span></td>
                    <td contenteditable='true'><?php echo $this->Form->number('quantity[]',['min'=>1, 'value'=>$cart_item->quantity]); ?></td>
                    <td><span id="total"><?php echo "$ AU".$cart_item->price * $cart_item->quantity?></span></td>
                </tr>
            <?php endforeach; ?>
            </tbody>
        </table>
        <?php }else{ ?>
            You don't have any items in your cart. Add more?
        <?php } ?>
    </fieldset>

        <?= $this->Form->button(__('Make a Payment'), ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->button(__('Update Cart'), ['controller' => 'Carts', 'action' => 'updateCart'], ['class' => 'btn btn-success']) ?>
        <?= $this->Form->end() ?>
        <?= $this->Form->postLink(__('Clear Cart'), ['controller' => 'Carts', 'action' => 'clearCart'], ['class' => 'btn btn-danger', 'confirm' => __('Are you sure you want to clear your cart?')]) ?>
</section>
```

> controller

```
public function updateCart()
    {
        if(isset($_SESSION['cart']) && !empty($_SESSION['cart'])){
            if ($this->request->is('post')) {
                $qty = $this->request->getData('quantity[]');
                debug($this->request->getData('quantity'));
            }
        }
        else{
            $this->Flash->error(__("You don't have anything in your cart. Add more?"));
        }
        $this->redirect(['controller'=>'Carts','action' => 'index']);
    }
```

Thank you

Comment: Do not access superglobals like `$_SESSION` directly, always use the abstracted APIs that CakePHP provides: **https://book.cakephp.org/4/en/development/sessions.html#accessing-the-session-object**. That being said, "_doesn't work_" is not a proper problem description, please explain what _exactly_ happens, and what _exactly_ you'd expected to happen instead! ps. please always mention your exact CakePHP version (last line in `lib/Cake/VERSION.txt` or `vendor/cakephp/cakephp/VERSION.txt`) - thanks!

Comment: You can get access to the array of quantity with $qty = $this->request->getData('quantity'); , you have added"[]" there. also you should take product id in another array as hidden field to know the quantity belongs to which product. then with the help of loop get all the product with quantity.